# Am I able to add a CSS property changer on a webpage using javascript?

Tags: javascript, css

I am using the template marketplace on Arcadier.com, and I just wanted to see how I can insert this line of code using Javascript to give users the ability to change the fonts on my marketplace.

I was thinking of just adding this code into the toolbox.

```
<script type="text/javascript">function resizeText(multiplier) { 
if (document.body.style.fontSize == "") {
 document.body.style.fontSize = ".0em";
  }
  document.body.style.fontSize = parseFloat(document.body.style.fontSize) + (multiplier * 0.2) + "em";
}</script>
```

Does anyone know how to specify the right area this code will affect once I throw it into the custom javascipt toolbox (image below)?

[Arcadier's admin 'custom code' tool box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZJghb.png)

Should I be using

```
•   document.getElementById("MyElement").className = "MyClass";
```

or

```
•   var path = window.location.pathname.toLowerCase()
```

(The second is from the e.g. that Arcadier gave)

Thank you!

Comment: Your code seems OK to me. Haven't it worked?

Comment: technical nits; this is not a font changer at all, this is a CSS property changer. The font tag is for questions about actual fonts. Also, HTML5 does not need "type=javascript", you only need `type` if the script is *not* JavaScript. Finally, use `===`: `==` allows for nonsense like `0`, `""`, and `false` all being considered the same thing